# Does HTTP Basic Access Authentication require Apache or Any 3rd Party Libraries?

Tags: http, authentication

I'm in the long process of creating an HTTP POST request.  I am trying to find the easiest way possible to add password and and username info. for authentication purposes and have concluded that HTTP Basic Access Authentication might be good.

My question is does HTTP Basic Access Authentication require ApacheHTTPClient or any 3rd party libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic Authentication is easy to implement. What you need is just a library for Base64.

1. Build a string by concatenating the user ID, a colon and the password. That is, "{userid}:{password}".
2. Encode the string by Base64.
3. Prepend "Basic " to the encoded string.
4. Set the resultant string to `Authorization` HTTP header.